# Examples of Object-Oriented Projects Help Procedural Programmers

Tags: java, c++, open-source, oop

Please help me identify some small to medium sized open source projects that embody object oriented design (preferably in C++ or Java).  I would like to use these projects to demonstrate how real world problems (as opposed to contrived text book examples) can be solved with an object oriented design.  I want to be able to present a plausible explanation of why certain things were chosen to be objects and how they all work together to solve a problem.

Comment: you are probably wasting your time: object-oriented concepts are best understood by doing, not by reading. If they didn't "get it" from the contrived textbook examples, they probably wont "get it" from more complex real-world examples, because neither of these are of interest to the audience. Show them the difference *in their own code* and they'll get it.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessarily a waste of time.  It depends on how a particular person processes information.  Personally, a lot of the coding habits/strategies I've developed were formed through reading other people's code.

Answer (score 2):

The [Unreal Tournament Public Source Code (432 Headers)](http://unreal.epicgames.com/Downloads.htm) contains the declarations of the Unreal engine class library written in C++. I found it to be a rich example of a *large* object-oriented program. It taught me a lot about how to modularize and object-orient my code. It also demonstrates many tactics for getting a handle on a large code base.

Also, because all you can read are header files, you'll have a fun (and educational) time trying to figure out how the whole thing comes together. (I actually ended up writing my own x86 disassembler so I could cheat and read some of the definitions!)

On the same note, the [Doom 3 SDK](http://www.iddevnet.com/doom3/downloads.php) contains a large chunk of the Doom/Quake engine written in very readable C++.

Answer (score 2):

Google [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) (C++): windows, tabs, plugins etc. are all classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any large project designed in Java is object-oriented, almost by definition.  You can take a look at [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) as a large-scale, open-source, objected oriented project written in Java.  Another is [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) would be a good example on the Java side: the plugin architecture is all object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same thing to my OO mentor.  He pointed me to the JUnit sources, with the recommendation to see how it evolved version by version.  This would show you how Kent Beck writes Java code.

Another example on this vein would be the sources of Fit by Ward Cunningham.